# Visual Studio 2013 - Debugger "hang" when using breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have had this problem on and off recently with a project I am working on in WPF & C#. The WPF uses an external DLL as an interface written in C++ so its always jumping between managed and unmanaged code (this may or may not be related).

I have found that placing breakpoints and stepping through, sometimes the debugger will just halt and not continue. This is not due to an assert or any other problem because hitting "break" will show the debug cursor at the same line. Just not continuing over it (it happens randomly, anywhere, anytime). This is really frustrating when debugging because the whole debug process has to start again from scratch.

Has anybody come across this and confirm this exists? If so, does anybody have a work around?

Comment: apply a mock instead of many managed-unmanged switches. if the debugging behaviour will be better, then you have your answer concerning your assumption.

Comment: but regardless if this fixes it or not, it still wont provide me with an answer of how to fix it. Also the point at which it halts is not at a point where its switching between

Comment: ok, then you should consider a code review about your stuff.

Comment: apart of that, are you using your vs within a vm with less ram. are you using the vs debugging mode in combination with an external component - hardware. had never an issue with vs 13.

Comment: none of the above, I have 32gigs of ram available